# How many permutations of order $8$ in $S_{10}$?

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics, permutations

> Find the number of permutations of order $8$ in $S_{10}$. If $\sigma$ is one of them, find the number of subgroups in the subgroup generated by $\sigma$.

Comment: Do you know about cycle decomposition? Do you know how to find the order of a permutation given its cycle decomposition?

Comment: Where is your input?

Comment: I can think of ${10\choose 8}=45$ for starters.   That is, the $8$-cycles.  But there are surely others.  Oh yeah, you can change their order.  So, multiply by $8!$?

Comment: @Chris Custer, no, you multiply by $7!$. Once you choose the image of $7$ elements in the cycle the last element has just one option.

Comment: @Mark  actually I think the reason is you can cyclically permute each $8$-cycle $8$ ways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An element of $S_{10}$ has order $8$ iff its cycle type is $(8,1,1)$ or $(8,2)$.

There are are ${10\choose 8}\cdot7!$ of type $(8,1,1)$.  There are ${10\choose 8}\cdot 7!$ of type $(8,2)$.

Together we get $900\cdot7!$

If $\sigma$ is one of them, $\langle\sigma \rangle $ is cyclic of order $8$.  Therefore there are two proper subgroups, of orders $2$ and $4$, other than $\{e\}$.

Comment: Hi, I'm reconsidering this question. Could you go into the combinatorial part in more detail? It's probably simpler than I think, but at the moment I can't understand the reason for the 7! Thank you.

Comment: There are $8!$ different ways of writing down an $8$ cycle;  but each $8$ cycle can be written $8$ different ways (by cyclically permuting it).  So we get $\frac{8!}8=7!$ $8$ cycles.

Comment: First you have to choose $8$ elements.   That's the reason for the $10\choose 8$.

Comment: For instance,  $(12345678)=(81234567)$.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but what you mean is that I can write this permutation (for example) (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8)(9 10) as (2 3 4 5 6 7 8 1)(9 10) or (3 4 5 6 7 8 1 2)(9 10) etc. Basically, they are the same permutation. Should they be included in the calculation anyway?

Comment: Correct.   They are the same permutation.   And there are $8$ ways of doing that.  Thus we divide by $8$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

The order of a permutation decomposed as a product of disjoint cycles is the l.c.m. of the orders of the cycles, i.e. the l.c.m. of the lengths of the cycles.

Comment: I think this needs some editing

Comment: @J.W.Tanner: Oh! yes. I've fixed it. Thanks for pointing the mistyping!

Comment: You are welcome !